# Debezium connector with TimescaleDB extension

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, timescaledb

I'm having trouble with detecting changes on Postresql hyper table(TimescaleDB extension).

Setup:

I have Postresql(ver 11.10) installed with TimescaleDB(ver 1.7.1) extension.
I have 2 tables I want to monitor them with Debezium(ver 1.3.1) connector installed on Kafka Connect for the purpose CDC(Capture Data Change).

Tables are table1 and table2hyper, but table2hyper is hypertable.

After creating Debezium connector in Kafka Connect I can see 2 topics created(one for each table):

- (A) kconnect.public.table1
- (B) kconnect.public.table2hyper

When consuming messages with kafka-console-consumer for topic A, I can see the messages after a row update in table1.

But when consuming messages from topic B(table2hyper table changes), nothing is emitted after for example a row update in table2hyper table.

Initialy Debezium connector does a snapshot of rows from table2hyper table and sends them to topic B(I can see the messages in topic B when using kafka-console-consumer), but changes that I do after the initial snapshot are not emitted.

Why am I unable to see subsequent changes(after initial snapshot) from table2hyper?

Connector creation payload:

```
{
    "name": "alarm-table-connector7",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "xxx",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "xxx",
        "database.password": "xxx",
        "database.dbname": "xxx",
        "database.server.name": "kconnect",
        "database.whitelist": "public.dev_db",
        "table.include.list": "public.table1, public.table2hyper",
        "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
        "tombstones.on.delete":"true",
        "slot.name": "slot3",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones":"false",
        "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode":"rewrite",
        "transforms.unwrap.add.fields":"table,lsn,op"
    }
}
```

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2):

After trying for a while, I did not succeed to stream data from hyper table with [Debezium](https://debezium.io/releases/) connector. I was using version 1.3.1. and upgrade to latest 1.4.1. did not help.

However, I did succeed with [Confluent JDBC connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc).

As far as my research and testing goes, this is the conclusion and feel free to correct me if necessary:

- Debezium works on ordinary tables on INSERT, UPDATE and
  DELETE events
- Confluent connector captures only INSERT events(unless you combine
  some columns for detecting changes) and works on ordinary and
  hyper(TimescaleDB) tables.

Answer (score 2):

we have never tested Debezium with TimescaleDB. I recommend you to check if TimescaleDB updates are present in logical rpelication slot. If yes it should be technically possible to have Debezium process the events. If not then is is not possible at all.

Comment: After fiddling with **pg_waldump** on currently active replication slot I found changes are present in the WAL log. Updating a row column in hyper table resulted in log:  

`...  
rmgr: Heap        len (rec/tot):    262/  7326, tx:     431132, lsn: 7/DF86DA70, prev 7/DF86DA38, desc: HOT_UPDATE off 31 xmax 431132 ; new off 32 xmax 0, blkref #0: rel 1663/100256/100315 blk 1 FPW
...`  

And after the column update, `*_lsn` columns increased when inspecting the active replication slot with `select * from pg_replication_slots;`  

So I'd say Debezium isn't picking hyper table updates.

Comment: What do you see if you use `pg_recvlogical` tool?

Comment: First I created the connector on 2 tables. One is hypertable, the other is not. Updates on hypertable do not get propagated to topic. Then I deleted the connector and used the same replication slot "debezium3" and the same publication "dbz_publication" created by connector to get the data. But updates on either tables did not give any output. Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

`pg_recvlogical -d XXX -U YYY -W --slot debezium3 --start -o proto_version=1 -o publication_names=dbz_publication -P pgoutput -f -`

Without proto_version=1 it said "but we only support protocol 1 or higher"

Comment: this is more verbose output [link](https://pastebin.com/1z5EBkv2). @JiriPechanec